# Check whether elements of vectors are inside intervals given by matrix

Tags: r, performance, loops, apply, intervals

Actually a really nice problem to which I came up with a solution (see below), which is, however, not beautiful:

Assume you have a **vector x** and a **matrix A** which contains the start of an interval in the first column and the end of the interval in the second.
How can I get the **elements of A**, which fall into the **intervals given by A**?

```
x <- c(4, 7, 15)

A <- cbind(c(3, 9, 14), c(5, 11, 16))
```

Expected output:

```
[1] 4 15
```

You could you the following information, if this would be helpful for increasing the performance:
Both, the vector and the rows of the matrix are ordered and the intervals **don't overlap**. All **intervals have the same length**. All numbers are **integers**, but can be **huge**.

Now I did not want to be lazy and came up with the following solution, which is too slow for long vectors and matrices:

```
x <- c(4, 7, 15)  # Define input vector

A <- cbind(c(3, 9, 14), c(5, 11, 16))  # Define matrix with intervals

b <- vector()

for (i in 1:nrow(A)) {
  b <- c(b, A[i, 1]:A[i, 2])
}

x[x %in% b]
```

I know that loops in *R* can be slow, but I did not know how to write the operation without one (maybe there is a way with `apply`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to loop over each element of `x` and find if it lies in the range of `any` of those matrix values.

```
x[sapply(x, function(i) any(i > A[, 1] & i < A[,2]))]
#[1]  4 15
```

---

In case, if `length(x)` and `nrow(A)` are same then we don't even need the `sapply` loop and we can use this comparison directly.

```
x[x > A[, 1] & x < A[,2]]
#[1]  4 15
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The length of x doesn't fit the number of rows in A. The first solution works, however.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that does not use an explicit loop or an apply function.  `outer` is sometimes much faster.

```
x[rowSums(outer(x, A[,1], `>=`) & outer(x, A[,2], `<=`)) > 0]

[1]  4 15
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. The solution works and it's very interesting to learn about a possible advantage in performance of `outer`. As is unfortunately the problem with optimized code: it is less readable for beginners.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki It is worth mentioning that this approach might use quite a lot of memory compared to the loops, as each call to `upper` creates a logical matrix, so if you have a very big dataset that might cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late, but today I had the same problem to solve and my answer is maybe helpful for future readers. My solution was the following:

```
f3 <- function(x,A) {
  Reduce(f = "|",
         x = lapply(1:NROW(A),function(k) x>A[k,1] & x<A[k,2]), 
         init = logical(length(x)))
}
```

This function return a logical vector of length(x) indicating whether the corresponding value in x can be found in the intervals or not. If I want to get the elements I simply have to write

```
x[f3(x,A)]
```

I did some benchmarks and my function seems to work very well, also while testing with larger data.
Lets define the other solutions suggested here in this post:

```
f1 <- function(x,A) {
  sapply(x, function(i) any(i > A[, 1] & i < A[,2]))
}

f2 <- function(x,A) {
  rowSums(outer(x, A[,1], `>`) & outer(x, A[,2], `<`)) > 0
}
```

Now they are also returning a logical vector.
The benchmarks on my machine are following:

```
x <- c(4, 7, 15)
A <- cbind(c(3, 9, 14), c(5, 11, 16))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(x,A), f2(x,A), f3(x,A))

#Unit: microseconds
#     expr  min    lq   mean median    uq  max neval
#f1(x, A) 21.5 23.20 25.023  24.30 25.40 61.8   100
#f2(x, A) 18.8 21.20 23.606  22.75 23.70 75.4   100
#f3(x, A) 13.9 15.85 18.682  18.30 19.15 52.2   100
```

It seems like there is no big difference, but the follwoing example will make it more obvious:

```
x <- seq(1,100,length.out = 1e6)
A <- cbind(20:70,(20:70)+0.5)
    
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(x,A), f2(x,A), f3(x,A), times=10)

#Unit: milliseconds
#     expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#f1(x, A) 4176.172 4227.6709 4419.6010 4484.2946 4539.9668 4569.7412    10
#f2(x, A) 1418.498 1511.5647 1633.4659 1571.0249 1703.6651 1987.8895    10
#f3(x, A)  614.556  643.4138  704.3383  672.5385  770.7751  873.1291    10
```

That the functions all return the same result can be checked e.g. via:

```
all(f1(x,A)==f3(x,A))
```